# Single field vs single clock inflation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

My question is very simple and short, but I couldn't find any explicit answer in papers and/or lecture notes.

**What is the difference between single field and single clock inflation?** Or, maybe, what is single clock inflation?

I know that single field is inflation driven in presence only of a unique field, i.e. both the rapid expansion *and* the generation of perturbations will originate from this field.

On the other hand, I heard at some point that single clock might mean that expansion is due to inflaton (and it can play the role of a clock), but then there might be an additional field (for instance curvaton) to generate the perturbations. But then is there any restrictions on what a single clock theory can be?

I'm not sure of what I am saying here. Any clarifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single clock inflation simply means that a single field's value has a one to one relationship with the scale factor $a$. For this to happen you need the field to be undergoing slow roll otherwise the expansion will depend on the field value and its time derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The single clock means only one field has a time-evolving background and drives inflation.

A multi-field inflation model can be a single-clock model if a field drives inflation and another massive field ($m \sim H$) whose background is not rolling but its fluctuations may be observable.